# Printer Samsung ML-2165W: Installed but it won't print

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, printing, samsung

I'm running Kubuntu 17.10

I connected the printer to the computer by USB and, in the Printers System Settings, click on Add Printer.

It detects my printer on the list, under Local Printers, and installs beautifully.

When I click on Maintenance > Print Test Page, the printer blinks and spins up!

But none of the test pages are ever printed. The Printers properties page shows its status as "In Use - 'Rendering completed'".

Later, if I unplug the printer from the PC, it prints out the following lines:

```
SPL ERROR - Incomplete Session by time out
POSITION : 0Xa0 (160)
SYSTEM: h6fw_5.57/os_hook
LINE: 1425
VERSION: SPL 5.57 01-12-2012
```

(The position changes each time.)

To make things worse, Samsung's printer support site seems to have been badly merged into HP's, because I can't even access certain links I find, such as http://www.samsung.com/br/support/model/ML-2165W/XAZ

But the printer works! Through USB on a Windows 10 laptop, and through WiFi on that laptop and even my phone! Just not on this machine...

Answer (score 1):

Try this site. http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/. I have a Samsung ML-1675 and I have been downloading my driver from this site for years everytime I do a fresh Linux install. Hope this helps.

Comment: I use this for three different printers and this works perfectly.  HP now seems to handle software support for Samsung printers...the vendors own Driver installer that I used to use is not there.  CUPS also works for 2 of my Samsung printers

Answer (score 0):

Even when it's detected in the list sometimes you have to go try the official driver. I also am having trouble finding official support for your model. If your model is the ML-2165W it looks like there's a Linux driver download here: http://www.samsungdrivers.net/samsung-ml-2165w-driver/ but that's not an official Samsung page so use at your own risk.

http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Samsung/Samsung-ML-2165W has one anonymous report that indicates someone else had trouble printing with it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are multiple types of drivers.  I've had printers that I could only get to print using a PCL driver in Ubuntu when PCL and Postscript drivers were available.

Answer (score 0):

I did install the driver from Samsung for my ML2165W and it works fine. I'll see if I can find the download page for you when I have access to the system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect browser to localhost:631 ; this will access the cups
   interface.
2. Add at least 1 "class" for your printer. The printer
   can't complete the connection without a class or else you see this
   type of timeout.

cups will show you a very detailed log of events. If you can't print a test page from cups, nothing will work.